# SQL_MODE is not being changed

Tags: mysql, heidisql, sql-mode

I have the latest mysql version, also i'm using HeidiSQL.

I've edited `my.ini`

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = ''
```

I've restarted the mysql server and when I query `SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;` I get again this:

`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

Also i've tried to set the sql_mode from the query, but it doesn't work...

```
SET @@GLOBAL.sql_mode= '';
```

I restart the server and the value is still unchanged, same as before `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, ...etc...`

Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: If you have edited my.ini and do not see the changes than ensure that you have edited the file which is used/loaded. `SET @@GLOBAL.sql_mode= '';` sets current runtime setting and does not effect permanent settings, so this setting is lost during the server restart, use `SET @@PERSIST.sql_mode= '';` instead. Study [System Variable Assignment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html#set-variable-system-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by going to `MySQL Workbench > Local Instance > Server > Options File > sql-mode and remove all that is inside (or whatever you want from there) > Apply > Restart MySQL Server`.

It seems editing the my.ini didn't work, so using MySQL Workbench it did work.